# Log4Net Dynamic logging folder path by exception

Tags: c#, log4net

How can I configure logging folder path by specified exception using log4net ?

I wanna specify logging folder at exception level, not at Appender level.
Something like that : "_log.Error(exception, {LogFolder});"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't be really doable unless you write a custom appender for it. This appender could work on context variables to retrieve the desired folder: in this case you would need to use an [event context](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/contexts.html)

Another way would be to create as many appenders as needed for exceptions you're interested in and filter each appender by an exception. For that you would need to create a custom filter based on a [`FilterSkeleton`](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Filter.FilterSkeleton.html)

Comment: Thanks @samy, You save my time !.